# Filtering out values with awk does not work properly

Tags: awk

First of all, I'm very new to the field, so if I did not add any information you need to help solve the problem, please ask.

Here's what I want to do: I have a file with 4 columns, and I want to filter out every row where the value for the 4th column is smaller than 20.

A line of code for awk works on a computer of a friend but not on mine, or better said it filters out some values but not all of them.

The head of my file looks like this

```
DS499594    6804    6805    6.000000
DS499594    8870    8871    1.000000
DS499594    26983   26984   56.000000
DS499594    27248   27249   6.000000
DS499594    27565   27566   11.000000
DS499594    27667   27668   15.000000
DS499594    27856   27857   19.000000
DS499594    27972   27973   3.000000
DS499594    28030   28031   5.000000
DS499594    28169   28170   8.000000
```

Then I run awk on this file with the following command

```
awk -F'\t' '$4 >= 20' /Users/lukasschrettenbrunner/Documents/3ENDcopy/test.bg  >> /Users/lukasschrettenbrunner/Documents/3ENDcopy/filtered.bg
```

then awk returns a file with the follwing file head

```
DS499594    6804    6805    6.000000
DS499594    26983   26984   56.000000
DS499594    27248   27249   6.000000
DS499594    27972   27973   3.000000
DS499594    28030   28031   5.000000
DS499594    28169   28170   8.000000
DS499594    28298   28299   9.000000
DS499594    28881   28882   4.000000
DS499594    29439   29440   4.000000
DS499594    29646   29647   7.000000
```

So yes, it filters out some rows but not all of them.
Does anyone has any idea about what's going on? The same line of code works on a computer of a friend, and awk filters out all values below 20 there.

I'm working with a MacBookPro with M2 Chip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that `.` is not the decimal separator for the locale setting on your computer so awk is treating your 4th field as strings rather than numbers and then doing a string (alphabetic) instead of numeric comparison. Try

```
LC_ALL=C awk '$4 >= 20' file
```

See [unable-to-print-period-thousands-separators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61910753/unable-to-print-period-thousands-separators/61911355?noredirect=1#comment109503378_61911355) for another locale issue plus various possible locale settings.

You could alternatively do:

```
awk '($4 + 0) >= 20' file
```

to turn $4 into an integer and thereby force a numeric comparison since you don't care about the part after the decimal point for that comparison anyway

Answer (score 0):

the landscape is more chaotic than i expected :

```
 5  DS499594    26983   26984   56.000000
 6  string 6.000000
 7  DS499594    27248   27249   6.000000
 8  string 11.000000
 9  string 15.000000
10  string 19.000000
11  string 3.000000
12  DS499594    27972   27973   3.000000
13  string 5.000000
14  DS499594    28030   28031   5.000000
15  string 8.000000
16  DS499594    28169   28170   8.000000
```

---

```
 2  strnum 1.000000
 3  strnum 56.000000
 4  DS499594    26983   26984   56.000000
 5  strnum 6.000000
 6  strnum 11.000000
 7  strnum 15.000000
 8  strnum 19.000000
 9  strnum 3.000000
10  strnum 5.000000
11  strnum 8.000000
```

---

- `nawk` and `mawk-1` seem to always follow locale rules, for better or worse.
- interestingly, `mawk-2` is entirely period based - couldn't even get it to obey locale rules at all
- `gawk` intentionally overrides the default behavior (as explicitly specified in the `man` page), and only emulates what `mawk-1 / nawk` look like when using either `gawk -N (--use-lc-numeric)` or `gawk -P (--posix)` flags

---

```
  mawk-2 1.9.9.6 | mawk-1 1.3.4-20230404
  gawk     5.2.1 | nawk (macOS) 20200816
```

ps : the full list of all locales I've tested that doesn't behave the same as `LC_ALL=C` :

```
af_ZA             es_ES             hy_AM.ARMSCII-8   pt_PT
af_ZA.ISO8859-1   es_ES.ISO8859-1   is_IS             pt_PT.ISO8859-1
af_ZA.ISO8859-15  es_ES.ISO8859-15  is_IS.ISO8859-1   pt_PT.ISO8859-15
be_BY             et_EE             is_IS.ISO8859-15  ro_RO
be_BY.CP1131      et_EE.ISO8859-15  it_CH             ro_RO.ISO8859-2

be_BY.CP1251      eu_ES             it_CH.ISO8859-1   ru_RU
be_BY.ISO8859-5   eu_ES.ISO8859-1   it_CH.ISO8859-15  ru_RU.CP1251
bg_BG             eu_ES.ISO8859-15  it_IT             ru_RU.CP866
bg_BG.CP1251      fi_FI             it_IT.ISO8859-1   ru_RU.ISO8859-5
ca_ES             fi_FI.ISO8859-1   it_IT.ISO8859-15  ru_RU.KOI8-R

ca_ES.ISO8859-1   fi_FI.ISO8859-15  kk_KZ             sk_SK
ca_ES.ISO8859-15  fr_BE             kk_KZ.PT154       sk_SK.ISO8859-2
cs_CZ             fr_BE.ISO8859-1   lt_LT             sl_SI
cs_CZ.ISO8859-2   fr_BE.ISO8859-15  lt_LT.ISO8859-13  sl_SI.ISO8859-2
da_DK             fr_CA             lt_LT.ISO8859-4   sr_YU

da_DK.ISO8859-1   fr_CA.ISO8859-1   nl_BE             sr_YU.ISO8859-2
da_DK.ISO8859-15  fr_CA.ISO8859-15  nl_BE.ISO8859-1   sr_YU.ISO8859-5
de_AT             fr_CH             nl_BE.ISO8859-15  sv_SE
de_AT.ISO8859-1   fr_CH.ISO8859-1   nl_NL             sv_SE.ISO8859-1
de_AT.ISO8859-15  fr_CH.ISO8859-15  nl_NL.ISO8859-1   sv_SE.ISO8859-15

de_CH             fr_FR             nl_NL.ISO8859-15  tr_TR
de_CH.ISO8859-1   fr_FR.ISO8859-1   no_NO             tr_TR.ISO8859-9
de_CH.ISO8859-15  fr_FR.ISO8859-15  no_NO.ISO8859-1   uk_UA
de_DE             hr_HR             no_NO.ISO8859-15  uk_UA.ISO8859-5
de_DE.ISO8859-1   hr_HR.ISO8859-2   pl_PL             uk_UA.KOI8-U

de_DE.ISO8859-15  hu_HU             pl_PL.ISO8859-2
el_GR             hu_HU.ISO8859-2   pt_BR
el_GR.ISO8859-7   hy_AM             pt_BR.ISO8859-1
```