# How to for loop file and print new line with awk for two columns

Tags: bash, awk

This is my file and I'm trying to process with the 4th and 5th column:

```
Server3 has 61 PG Plan1
Server3 has 29 PG Plan6
Server4 has 18 PG Plan4
Server3 has 21 PG Plan2
Server6 has 31 PG Plan8
Server8 has 12 PG Plan3
Server3 has 10 BG Plan7
Server5 has 45 BG Plan5
```

This shows fine (logically):

```
awk '{print $4, $5}' file
```

Output:

```
PG Plan1
PG Plan6
PG Plan4
PG Plan2
PG Plan8
PG Plan3
BG Plan7
BG Plan5
```

But when I try a `for` loop, all are printed in the same line:

```
cat file | while read line; do echo $(awk '{print $4, $5}'); done
```

Output:

```
PG Plan6 PG Plan4 PG Plan2 PG Plan8 PG Plan3 BG Plan7 BG Plan5
```

I tried these but I still see the above output:

```
cat file | while read line; do echo $(awk '{print $4} {print $5} {printf "\n"}'); done
cat file | while read line; do echo $(awk '{print $4, $5}'); done
```

How can I print two columns of 4th and 5th together in the same line and then print a `\n` new line for another loop?

Expected output is:

```
PG Plan1
PG Plan6
PG Plan4
PG Plan2
PG Plan8
PG Plan3
BG Plan7
BG Plan5
```

**Update 1**

As asked in the comments why not using `awk '{print $4, $5}' file` when it works and shows expected output, the goal is to compare to files and if they match, do something.

This is `file` (which stated before here):

```
Server3 has 61 PG Plan1
Server3 has 29 PG Plan6
Server4 has 18 PG Plan4
Server3 has 21 PG Plan2
Server6 has 31 PG Plan8
Server8 has 12 PG Plan3
Server3 has 10 BG Plan7
Server5 has 45 BG Plan5
```

This is `anotherfile`:

```
-
  gpid: 46
  gpname: "Some MadeUp Name (Not Important)"
  pid: 308
  name: "PG Plan1"
  monthly: 100.00
-
  gpid: 46
  gpname: "Some MadeUp Name (Not Important)"
  pid: 308
  name: "PG Plan6"
  monthly: 187.00
-
  gpid: 46
  gpname: "Some MadeUp Name (Not Important)"
  pid: 308
  name: "PG Plan4"
  monthly: 155.00
-
  gpid: 46
  gpname: "Some MadeUp Name (Not Important)"
  pid: 308
  name: "PG Plan2"
  monthly: 125.00
-
  gpid: 46
  gpname: "Some MadeUp Name (Not Important)"
  pid: 308
  name: "PG Plan8"
  monthly: 225.00
-
  gpid: 46
  gpname: "Some MadeUp Name (Not Important)"
  pid: 308
  name: "PG Plan3"
  monthly: 140.00
-
  gpid: 46
  gpname: "Some MadeUp Name (Not Important)"
  pid: 308
  name: "BG Plan7"
  monthly: 200.00
-
  gpid: 46
  gpname: "Some MadeUp Name (Not Important)"
  pid: 308
  name: "BG Plan5"
  monthly: 176.00
-
```

The final goal (I'm going step-by-step but I don't know yet the command to reach below):

> for every line in `file` and column 4 and 5, check if the `name ==`  to the `name` in `anotherfile`, then multiply the 3rd column of `file` by `monthly` in `anotherfile` and calculate the result of each one.

Expected output:

```
Server3 has 61 PG Plan1 (profit 6,100)
Server3 has 29 PG Plan6 (profit 3,625)
Server4 has 18 PG Plan4 (profit 2,790)
Server3 has 21 PG Plan2 (profit 2,625)
Server6 has 31 PG Plan8 (profit 6,975)
Server8 has 12 PG Plan3 (profit 1,680)
Server3 has 10 BG Plan7 (profit 2,000)
Server5 has 45 BG Plan5 (profit 7,920)
```

Comment: `awk '{print $4, $5}' file` already gives you the expected output, which doesn't seem to agree with your description of what you want. Please clarify

Comment: to maintain the linefeeds try wrapping the subshell invocation in double quotes, eg: `echo "$(awk '{print $4, $5}')"`; this still only prints the last 2 lines because the `read line` has consumed the first line

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes, but I want to use an `if` clause to compare two files if the names are equal, do something. Since it wasn't necessary info for this question, I didn't add.

Comment: Then I suggest changing the example input so that the expected output will require something more advanced than `awk '{print $4, $5}'`.

Comment: Both your first and last "expected" output are the same. Please clarify what you want to do. Are you trying to implement a solution in Bash instead of the Awk? Add another example that gives difference.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I think the answer should work for me for the actual scenario I try.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'll edit the question soon to say why (at least what you said doesn't provide my expected output which I tested myself too, but I don't know why).

Comment: @TedLyngmo I edited the question and simulate what I'm finally trying to have.

Comment: Btw, is that a yaml file you have there?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm afraid I don't understand your meaning exactly. Let's think we have no `Brand X` and only we have is the current edition of question. Regarding `yaml`, no, all data are `plain text`. The prices are currently `yaml` file but they may become plain text in the future (but it doesn't matter in this case).

Comment: @TedLyngmo oops, thanks. I forgot to edit that part.

Comment: while the latter update (additional file named `anotherfile`, 2nd set of expected output showing `profit`) is somewhat helpful, it now complicates the original question; actually, you now have two completely different questions, and these latest updates now invalidate any answers you've received up to this point; I would suggest you edit (again) the current question and remove everything having to do with the 2nd question (`anotherfile`, `profit` output); then ask a new question on how to join the contents of the two files to generate the `profit` output ....

Comment: @markp-fuso I just added to say the reason why `awk {'print $4, $5'}` doesn't meet my requirement as TedLyngmo commented.

Comment: fwiw, while an answer to the 2nd question (`anotherfile`, `profit` output) could make use of a `bash/while/read` loop, a more efficient (and faster) solution will likely skip the `bash/while/read` loop in favor of some other tool/language (eg, `awk`, `perl`, etc)

Comment: What you describe should be done in a single call to awk, no shell loop required. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: @EdMorton thanks, can you help me more? I'm now trying to add some more commands to reach my final goal. But I'm finding `awk` very interesting but I'm a newbie for it:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR == FNR {
    if ( /^-/ ) {
        name2monthly[tag2val["name"]] = tag2val["monthly"]
    }
    else {
        gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"")
        tag = val = $0
        sub(/:.*/,"",tag)
        sub(/[^:]*:[[:space:]]*/,"",val)
        gsub(/^"|"$/,"",val)
        tag2val[tag] = val
    }
    next
}
{
    printf "%s (profit %\047d)\n", $0, $3 * name2monthly[$4" "$5]
}
```

```
$ LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 awk -f tst.awk anotherfile file
Server3 has 61 PG Plan1 (profit 6,100)
Server3 has 29 PG Plan6 (profit 5,423)
Server4 has 18 PG Plan4 (profit 2,790)
Server3 has 21 PG Plan2 (profit 2,625)
Server6 has 31 PG Plan8 (profit 6,975)
Server8 has 12 PG Plan3 (profit 1,680)
Server3 has 10 BG Plan7 (profit 2,000)
Server5 has 45 BG Plan5 (profit 7,920)
```

The above is first creating an array of tag to value pairs (e.g. tag `pid` maps to value `308` in every record) for every line in the current `-`-separate record of `anotherfile`, then creating an array `name2monthly` that maps every name value to the monthly value in that same record at the end of each record.

Then it reads `file` and just multiplies $3 by the `monthly` value stored in `name2monthly[]` for the given $4 $5 `name` pair.

Comment: Thanks Ed, my `awk` version is `GNU Awk 5.1.0, API: 3.0 (GNU MPFR 4.1.0, GNU MP 6.2.1)`, but the output doesn't have thousand separator.

Comment: The thousand separator works fine in the server, but in my WSL it doesn't add any `,`:(. My server's version is `GNU Awk 4.2.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 3.1.6-p2, GNU MP 6.1.2)`

Comment: @Saeed I've got this answer working with `GNU awk 4.1.4` and `GNU awk 5.2.1`; did you include the (required) `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` assignment as shown?

Comment: @markp-fuso yes, I included `LC=...` too in both my laptop's WSL and the Ubuntu Server. The strange thing is in my laptop it doesn't add `,` but in Ubuntu Server works properly. Any other thing is important here?

Comment: that's `LC_ALL=` .... not `LC=`; another possibility could be that you don't have the `en_US.UTF-8` locale available in the WSL environment

Comment: @markp-fuso yes, I was only typing it in comments, but I copied exactly what Ed wrote.

Comment: `locale -a` to see a list of available locales

Comment: The problems with your environment, not your gawk version. You'll have to research how to set the locale to one that uses commas as the thousands separator in whatever "WSL" is (or just add a `,` every 3 chars from the right before printing the number).

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/249116/133219 and/or https://stackoverflow.com/a/61911355/1745001 or just google "awk print thousands separator" or similar.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see them later since WSL is not important for me. But there's an issue: there are some plans which are exactly the same name as the file and anotherfile, but it counts 0 profit. There are a couple of these issues.

Comment: Then, since it's been a few days now and you have multiple answers, accept an answer to the question you asked here and then ask a new question with whatever data is causing that if you can't figure out how to solve it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Addressing OP's first/original question re: using a `while/read` loop to process lines and display the 4th and 5th fields ...

Assumptions:

- OP needs both `$line` as well as the 4th and 5th fields (from `$line`) for some (as yet undefined) purpose within the `while` loop, otherwise a simple one-line `awk` script would be easier/faster for printing the 4th/5th fields

One approach:

```
while read -r line
do
    read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 rest_of_line <<< "$line"     # split $line on spaces placing contents in variables f{1..5} and rest_of_line (just in case there might be more than 5 fields)
    echo "$line : $f4 : $f5"
done < file
```

**NOTES:**

- this eliminates the unnecessary use of `cat`
- this elimnates all subshell invocations (eg, `cat file |` , `$(awk ...)`)
- this allows other variables to be populated insided the `while` loop and then used later in the script (outside the `while` loop)

This generates:

```
Server3 has 61 PG Plan1 : PG : Plan1
Server3 has 29 PG Plan6 : PG : Plan6
Server4 has 18 PG Plan4 : PG : Plan4
Server3 has 21 PG Plan2 : PG : Plan2
Server6 has 31 PG Plan8 : PG : Plan8
Server8 has 12 PG Plan3 : PG : Plan3
Server3 has 10 BG Plan7 : BG : Plan7
Server5 has 45 BG Plan5 : BG : Plan5
```

---

If OP does not need the contents of `$line` then we can combine the two `read` commands:

```
while read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 rest_of_line
do
    echo "$f4 : $f5"
done < file
```

This generates:

```
PG : Plan1
PG : Plan6
PG : Plan4
PG : Plan2
PG : Plan8
PG : Plan3
BG : Plan7
BG : Plan5
```

Comment: Thanks, but what is `frest`?

Comment: I mean I have nothing after the 5th column, but why is `frest` needed? I don't understand that. I also remove `frest` from the code and I don't see any changes.

Comment: from the comments in the script: *`frest will contain everything after the 5th field`*; after f1/f2/f3/f4/f5 you have `f[rest_of_line]`; it's just a placeholder for anything that might come after the 5th space-delimited field; granted, no such field exists in your sample input data but it doesn't hurt to place that rest-of-line bucket, just in case; the name could be anything ... `frest`, `f6_to_eol`, `restofline`; in fact, think I'll go ahead and call it `rest_of_line` ...

Comment: yes, in this case if you know with 100% certainty that you'll have exactly 5 fields then `frest` (renamed `rest_of_line`) is not needed (in the current case it'll be blank); I tend to add this last variable *just in case* the sample input file has > 5 fields; another common solution you'll see ... `while read -r _ _ _ f4 f5 _` which says to place the contents of the 1st, 2nd, 3rd and everything-after-the-5th fields into the variable named `_` (effectively ignore all but the 4th/5th fields)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `echo` and the `$line` variable get lost the way they are used in the question. This should work:

```
cat file | while read line; do echo "$line" | awk '{print $4, $5}'; done
```

If a subshell is absolutely necessary, this should work too:

```
cat file | while read line; do echo $(echo "$line" | awk '{print $4, $5}'); done
```

Comment: I had to have a loop for this but I didn't find any way to use `$line` for this. It works as expected.

Comment: micromoses: You seem to have understood what OP wants so can you please explain what your answer does that wasn't already done by `awk '{print $4, $5}'`?

Comment: It was explained in one of the comments to the question; They need to run an action for each line (comparison), so each line needed to be processed individually, instead of passing the entire file to `awk`. There might be more elegant ways to accomplish this, but as there may be other unknown constraints, I opted to keep it as close to the original code as possible.

Comment: @micromoses Ok, it'll be interesting to see OPs edit that was promised.

Comment: @micromoses I edited the question and wrote my goal.

Comment: That script contains multiple anti-patterns, e.g. UUOC, no IFS= or -r on the read loop, no quotes around the echo argument. If you copy/paste it into http://shellecheck.net that'll tell you more about some of the issues.