# How to partially search for a string in awk and calculate the values

Tags: bash, awk

Prior to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76500719/how-to-for-loop-file-and-print-new-line-with-awk-for-two-columns),
I tried some failed and even syntax-failed codes which resulted to fail.

These are plan names (plans.txt):

```
-
  gpid: 46
  gpname: "Some MadeUp Name (Not Important)"
  pid: 308
  name: "AG Plan1"
  monthly: 100.00
-
  gpid: 46
  gpname: "Some MadeUp Name (Not Important)"
  pid: 309
  name: "BG Plan1 R"
  monthly: 100.00
-
  gpid: 46
  gpname: "Some MadeUp Name (Not Important)"
  pid: 310
  name: "VG Plan1"
  monthly: 100.00
-
  gpid: 46
  gpname: "Some MadeUp Name (Not Important)"
  pid: 310
  name: "VG Plan2 R1"
  monthly: 100.00
-
```

This is my text trying to process (main.txt):

```
Server1 has 1 AG Plan1
Server2 has 1 CG Plan2
Server3 has 1 BG Plan1
Server4 has 1 DG Plan1
```

What plans are equal (if possible, write the conditions separately in a .txt file or something like an array):

> in server1 or server2 --> (AG Plan1 *) == AG Plan1

> in server1 or server2 --> (BG Plan2 *) == AG Plan2

> in server3 or server4 --> (VG Plan1 *) == VG Plan1

> in server3 or server4 --> (VG Plan2 *) == VG Plan2

There are also silimar names for Plan2, Plan3 and so on (if matters, let me know to add).

The conditions are:

1. if hostname == server1.domain or hostname == server2.domain --> check the fifth column of main.txt and find AG PlanX, then multiply third column by the plan price.
2. if hostname == server3.domain or hostname == server4.domain --> check the fifth column of main.txt and find VG PlanX, then multiply third column by the plan price.

Expected output in `server1` and `server2`:

```
Server1 has 1 AG Plan1 (profit 100)
Server2 has 1 AG Plan2 (profit 100)
```

Expected output in `server3` and `server4`:

```
Server3 has 1 VG Plan1 (profit 100)
Server4 has 1 VG Plan2 (profit 100)
```

I'm trying to read the docs and everything related to `awk`, but I cannot still find a way to reach this.

**َUpdate 1 to clarify my question (I think reading from Update 1 makes more sense)**

These are plan names (plans.txt):

```
-
  gpid: 46
  gpname: "Some MadeUp Name (Not Important)"
  pid: 308
  name: "NewClusterA Plan1"
  monthly: 100.00
-
  gpid: 46
  gpname: "Some MadeUp Name (Not Important)"
  pid: 309
  name: "OldClusterA Plan1"
  monthly: 100.00
-
  gpid: 46
  gpname: "Some MadeUp Name (Not Important)"
  pid: 310
  name: "OldClusterA Plan1 Old"
  monthly: 100.00
-
  gpid: 46
  gpname: "Some MadeUp Name (Not Important)"
  pid: 311
  name: "NewClusterB Plan1"
  monthly: 100.00
-
  gpid: 46
  gpname: "Some MadeUp Name (Not Important)"
  pid: 312
  name: "OldClusterB Plan1"
  monthly: 100.00
-
  gpid: 46
  gpname: "Some MadeUp Name (Not Important)"
  pid: 313
  name: "OldClusterB Plan1 Old"
  monthly: 100.00
-
```

This is my text trying to process (main.txt):

```
Server1 has 1 NewClusterA Plan1
Server2 has 1 OldClusterA Plan1
Server1 has 1 OldClusterA Plan1 Old
Server3 has 1 NewClusterB Plan1
Server4 has 1 OldClusterB Plan1
Server3 has 1 OldClusterB Plan1 Old
```

What plans are equal (if possible, write the conditions separately in a `.txt` file or something like an array):

> in server1 or server2 --> (OldClusterA Plan1 *) == NewClusterA Plan1 (I mean the price of both are the same and also the resources they have)

> in server3 or server4 --> (OldClusterA Plan1 *) == NewClusterB Plan1 (I mean the price of both are the same and also the resources they have)

There are also silimar names for Plan2, Plan3 and so on (if matters, let me know to add).

The conditions are:

1. if hostname == server1.domain or hostname == server2.domain --> check the fifth column of main.txt and find `Old/NewClusterA PlanX`, then multiply third column by the plan price.
2. if hostname == server3.domain or hostname == server4.domain --> check the fifth column of main.txt and find `Old/NewClusterB PlanX`, then multiply third column by the plan price.

Expected output in `server1` and `server2`:

```
Server1 has 1 NewClusterA Plan1 (profit 100)
Server2 has 1 NewClusterA Plan2 (profit 100)
```

Expected output in `server3` and `server4`:

```
Server3 has 1 NewClusterB Plan1 (profit 100)
Server4 has 1 NewClusterB Plan2 (profit 100)
```

I'm trying to read the docs and everything related to `awk`, but I cannot still find a way to reach this.

I read some other docs related to `awk` and tried processing two files, but I didn't find a way for the conditions I have.

**Update 2**

Since all plan names in both cluster should be changed to `New` name with no more suffix (I mean `OldClusterA Plan1 Old` should be change to `NewClusterA Plan1`), I found a workaround to replace them with `sed`. No user in server3 or server4 uses `ClusterA`'s plan and no user in server1 or server2 uses `ClusterB`'s plan.

Comment: That's because there isn't much tying the two file together logically to make processing with `awk` straight-forward. The only doc you need for `awk` (for the most part) is the [GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents) and specifically the [String Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#String-Functions) section for a majority of what this problem requires.

Comment: [edit] your question to show your attempt to solve your problem so we can help you with that. The "profit" stuff seems to have nothing to do with **this problem** and I'm pretty sure you already have a solution for that part so including it again here just obfuscates your problem. Come up with and post a [mcve] that's just about **this** problem.

Comment: @EdMorton I just solved my problem by another way, without solutions friends here provided. I'll discuss later.

Comment: @Saeed that doesn't matter. You asked a question here and people put effort into helping you solve your problem so you should carry through to the point where you have accepted an answer so their effort wasn't a waste of time as others in future with a similar problem could then benefit from their answers even if you don't.

Comment: @EdMorton sure, I don't intend to waste their time. For sure the way and solutions here are much much better than mine.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks a lot sir, I edited the question to be more clear and nearer to the reality (at least in my mind, which may not be correct). I'm newbie in `awk` and I don't know much of this language:(

Comment: DO NOT DELETE text from your original question -- that makes all comments and answers before your edit no longer make sense. Instead ADD new files below the original question so ALL answers and comments continue to make sense.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I'm so sorry. You're right. I didn't mean to offend anyone:( I just tried to make my question clearer. I edited the question again and added an update for what I added

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I think you really don't get all the instructions or the files are stripped to the point they lose the correlation between each other....

In this case, the big problem is there is no correlation whatsoever between the files to relate `"AG Plan2"` to anything. There is very little else to relate the information in the files beyond that. The best you can do is use the *"Server Number"*, e.g. the `X` in `"ServerX"` as an index to correlate the `plan` (e.g., `"AG Plan1"`, `"AG Plan2"`, ...) with the price extracted as the 2nd field in each `monthly:` record.

The only way to handle your magic `"BG Plan1"` => `"AG Plan2"` is with a lookup table (simple array that maps the plan `"BG Plan1"` => `"AG Plan2"`). Then you can use a `(plan in lookup)` test to see if the replacement from the lookup table should be used, or whether the plan extracted from `plans.txt` will do.

You can do it with 3-rules (not counting `BEGIN` used to setup your `lookup[]` array). The 2nd (middle) rule starts the processing looking for the `name:` records in `plans.txt`. When found, `match()` is used to locate the substring between double-quotes setting the `awk` internal variables `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` allowing you to use `substr()` to extract the text between the double-quotes.  You can also save a dynamic regex in a variable that can help in some cases.

Then you use `split` to split the extracted string on whitespace and take the first two elements as your `plan`. Then the `getprice` flag is set to `1` (`true`) to indicate to the 1st rule that it can now locate the `monthly:` record and get the price to go with that plan.

After all your price and plan information is saved from `plans.txt`, you can simply read through `main.txt` extracting the last digit from the `ServerX` field to use as the index to relate your plan, price and Server together outputting what you need.

Putting it altogether, you can do something similar to:

```bash
#!/bin/awk -f

# lookup table for "BG Plan1" => "AG Plan2" with NO correlation in files
BEGIN { lookup["BG Plan1"] = "AG Plan2" }

# reading plan.txt (1st file)
# if plan found and getprice flas set, read price and create indexed arrays
# label[] and price[] providing relationship between price and plan name
NR == FNR && getprice && /^[[:space:]]*monthly:/ {
  # label is plan (e.g. AG Plan1) unless in lookup[], then use lookup[]
  label[++n] = (plan in lookup) ? lookup[plan] : plan
  price[n] = $2         # set price from 2nd field
  getprice = 0          # reset getprice flag zero
  next                  # skip to next record
}

# reading plan.txt (1st file), locate "name:" record
NR == FNR && /^[[:space:]]*name:/ {
  match ($0, /"[^"]+"/)                     # set RSTART, RLENGTH on "
  plan = substr($0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-2)    # save substring as plan
  split (plan, arr, /[[:space:]]/)          # split plan on whitespace
  plan = arr[1] " " arr[2]                  # take 1st two components as plan
  getprice = 1                              # set getprice flag
  next                                      # skip to next record
}

# reading main.txt (2nd file), process ServerX
NR != FNR {
  servernum = $1                            # save 1st field as servernum
  sub (/^[^[:digit:]]*/, "", servernum)     # remove all but last digit
  # use last digit (server number) to relate label and price for output
  print $1, $2, $3, label[servernum], "(profit", $3 * price[servernum] ")"
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

With the script in `serverplan.awk` (and made executable with `chmod +x serverplan.awk`) and your data in your original `plans.txt` and `main.txt`:

```
$ cat plans.txt
-
  gpid: 46
  gpname: "Some MadeUp Name (Not Important)"
  pid: 308
  name: "AG Plan1"
  monthly: 100.00
-
  gpid: 46
  gpname: "Some MadeUp Name (Not Important)"
  pid: 309
  name: "BG Plan1 R"
  monthly: 100.00
-
  gpid: 46
  gpname: "Some MadeUp Name (Not Important)"
  pid: 310
  name: "VG Plan1"
  monthly: 100.00
-
  gpid: 46
  gpname: "Some MadeUp Name (Not Important)"
  pid: 310
  name: "VG Plan2 R1"
  monthly: 100.00
-
```

and

```
$ cat main.txt
Server1 has 1 AG Plan1
Server2 has 1 CG Plan2
Server3 has 1 BG Plan1
Server4 has 1 DG Plan1
```

you would do:

```
$ ./serverplan.awk plans.txt main.txt
Server1 has 1 AG Plan1 (profit 100)
Server2 has 1 AG Plan2 (profit 100)
Server3 has 1 VG Plan1 (profit 100)
Server4 has 1 VG Plan2 (profit 100)
```

Which matches your expected output precisely.

Look things over and let me know if you have questions. I have a hard time imagining you actually have the question written up as you actually need it. There is just very little to piece things together with.

Comment: Thanks sir. Regarding correlation between the files, I try my best to simulate the actual values with less explanations for details (I mean I try my question he clear enough). I may edit the inputs and outputs to be more real.

Comment: Yes, that may help (may not). This was a tricky problem if this is really all the correlation you had to work with. It was a good problem, but well beyond any conceivable problem for those just "Learning Awk". This was a challenge....

Comment: Also, the `NR == FNR` (total number of records == file number of records) is only true when processing the 1st file, so you can use that to separate which rules apply to the 1st file and the rules that will apply to all remaining files. You choose your first file based on needing to store data from that file to use in processing the remaining files. (that just takes a bit of practice -- a lot of practice) to get comfortable with.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin : hmmmm… what do you mean by :::::::::::::::::::::: ::::::::  :::::::::::::: ::::::::::::::: :::::::::::::::::  `"you cannot use double-quotes in the REGEX"` ? :::::::::::::: : :::::::::::::: :::::::::::::::: ::::::     `jot -c 10 33 | gawk '/["]/' ` —> `"` ::::::::: and technically, even those square brackets are superfluous ::::::::::::: ::::::::::::: just `mawk '/"/'` suffices

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks a lot sir, I edited the question to be more clear and nearer to the reality (at least in my mind, which may not be correct).

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto - good catch, I had string stuck in my mind as that was what I was matching. (but it sure does screw up syntax highlighting `:)` The character class (square brackets) and not superfluous here, the `'^'` negates the match within them.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin : my bad i meant my own square brackets were superfluous, not yours. i have this annoying habit of thinking out loud like that, something i need to fix. But in terms of strings youre absolutely right - I always use `\47 \42 \140` for single-quote, double-quote, and backticks in strings to avoid issues down the road.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanna quickly mention that `NR == FNR` ***does not*** mean you could only use it for the first file.

By resetting `NR` whenever you're at first row of each file other than the last one, one could easily perform a 3+ file join like this ::

```
  mawk ' 1 ==  FNR && FILENAME != ARGV[ARGC - 1] { NR = FNR }
        NR ==  FNR \
  ? (__[NR] = __[ NR] FILENAME  " \42" $0 "\42 ") < "" \
  :     $0  = __[FNR] "| Last File \42" $0 "\42 | FNR,NR => "FNR","NR' \
                                                 \
          <( jot -w '%+g'    5 -3.14159 - 2.71828 ) \
          <( jot -c          5       67          ) \
          <( jot -w 'U+%.4X' 5    63743         )
```

---

```
/dev/fd/11 "-3.14159" /dev/fd/12 "C" | Last File "U+F8FF" | FNR,NR => 1,6
/dev/fd/11 "-0.42331" /dev/fd/12 "D" | Last File "U+F900" | FNR,NR => 2,7
/dev/fd/11 "+2.29497" /dev/fd/12 "E" | Last File "U+F901" | FNR,NR => 3,8
/dev/fd/11 "+5.01325" /dev/fd/12 "F" | Last File "U+F902" | FNR,NR => 4,9
/dev/fd/11 "+7.73153" /dev/fd/12 "G" | Last File "U+F903" | FNR,NR => 5,10
```

---

The final value of `NR` is **`10`**, despite **`15`** rows being read in in total.

The array was created with `NR` as its hash key instead of `FNR`, but read back out via `FNR`. It was intentionally done this way to illustrate that `NR` is very much a fungible variable that one could leverage to their advantage.

`POSIX` rules, to my best knowledge, never mentioned anything about `NR` or `FNR` being read-only to the end-user. At the fringes and extreme, you can even setup a perfectly `POSIX-compliant` scenario where `NR < FNR`, e.g.:

---

```
 FNR == 1 { NR = FILENAME != ARGV[ARGC - 1] \
                 \
            ? FNR : 111 - 2^53 } # This happens to be the (now-negated) 
                                 # largest prime supported to full precision 
                                 # by IEEE 754 double floating point
```

---

The end result is `NR` being sent ***waaaaaaay*** into the negative zone :

---

```
..fd/11 "-3.14159" ..fd/12 "C" | 3rdFn "U+F8FF" | FNR,NR = 1,-9007199254740881
..fd/11 "-0.42331" ..fd/12 "D" | 3rdFn "U+F900" | FNR,NR = 2,-9007199254740880
..fd/11 "+2.29497" ..fd/12 "E" | 3rdFn "U+F901" | FNR,NR = 3,-9007199254740879
..fd/11 "+5.01325" ..fd/12 "F" | 3rdFn "U+F902" | FNR,NR = 4,-9007199254740878
..fd/11 "+7.73153" ..fd/12 "G" | 3rdFn "U+F903" | FNR,NR = 5,-9007199254740877
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, I edited the question to be more clear and nearer to the reality (at least in my mind, which may not be correct).

Comment: @Saeed : oh i wasn't directing this at you, but more for comments elsewhere in the thread that might undersell `awk`'s convenience - and that multi-way joins are potentially as straight forward as resetting `NR` so one could re-use the `NR == FNR` condition over and over again for multiple input files.

Comment: @Saeed : and I totally understand why `"resetting NR"` is a notion few are willing to even entertain, since none of the documentation (or `POSIX` spec itself) provide examples of it, let alone encourage its use, despite `"resetting NR"` being a fully `POSIX`-compliant way to use `awk` (in fact, any of the items set by `awk` and specified by the spec, other than `NF < 0` being a fatal error, one can fudge any of them, and `awk` wouldn't show a warning at all - e.g. `split( $2, ARGV )` is actually permissible by the spec.