# How to convert the input balance 22222222.22 to the german format 2.222.222,22

Tags: linux, xml, shell, awk

i am try to convert the value from input xml like 2222222.22 ot the german format like 2.222.222,22.
Here is the block of the code with the while function

```
                # Remove any existing dots as thousand separators and replace dot with comma as decimal separator
            tag2val[tags[i]] = gensub(/\./, ",", "g", tag2val[tags[i]])
            # Add dots as thousand separators if necessary
            while (match(tag2val[tags[i]], /[0-9]{4}/)) {
                tag2val[tags[i]] = substr(tag2val[tags[i]], 1, RSTART) "." substr(tag2val[tags[i]], RSTART+1)
            }
```

of course this script need to work no matter if the value is 2.22 or 222.22 or 22222222.22
Any help?

Comment: A number is a number is a number.  Depending on the culture a string is automatically converted to/from a number.  Only when you reading/writing  a number in a different culture do you need to converted

Comment: In Coreutils, there's [`numfmt`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/numfmt-invocation.html) that can print numbers in different formats, including locale-dependent; it's not straightforward to use it to convert formats between locales, though.

Comment: please update the question to include a minimal, complete working set of code, the sample inputs and the (wrong) output generated by your code; also, are you looking for a locale independent solution or should the answer be locale specific (and if so then update the question with your locale)

Comment: consider a web search (eg, `awk thousands separator`) ... lots of hits including SO/SE/sister sites (eg, [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/249116) or the [GNU awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Format-Modifiers.html)

Comment: `sub(/\./,",",tag2val[tags[i]]); while(tag2val[tags[i]] ~ /[0-9]{4}/) sub(/[0-9]{3}[\.,]/,".&",tag2val[tags[i]])`?

Comment: is the input guaranteed to always have 2 digits after the decimal? could the input include something like `2.1234`?

Comment: Have you to use `awk` AT ANY PRICE or are you accepting using other tools?

Answer (score 1):

Just set your locale to one that displays numbers formatted as you want, e.g.:

```
$ echo '2222222.22' | LC_ALL=de_DE awk '{printf "%\047.02f\n", $0}'
2.222.222,22

$ echo '2222222.22' | LC_ALL=da_DK awk '{printf "%\047.02f\n", $0}'
2.222.222,22
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61911355/1745001 for some other locale possibilities and how to find one that works for you if neither of the above 2 do.

Answer (score 0):

A "C style" solution, works with any Awk:

```
$ cat data.txt
2.22
22.22
222.22
2222.22
22222.22
222222.22
2222222.22
```

```
$ cat filter.awk
{
   len = split( $0, a, "" ) 
   for ( i = len; i > 0; i-- )  # traverse the record character by character, 
   {                            #> in reverse: -> 22.2222222 ->
      n++
      m++

      if ( n == 3 )  # n: comma position counter: 
      {              #> 3rd pos? replace the dot with comma
         a[i] = ","
         m -= 4      # m: dot position counter: 
      }              #> decreased to -1 at the 3rd pos, will be 3 at the 7th pos

      if (( n > 6 ) && ( m % 3 == 0 ))  # we are at the 7th pos, time to insert a dot
      {
         rec = "." rec  # to get the reversed record right, build it in reverse
      }

      rec = a[i] rec  # ditto
   }

   print rec
   len = i = n = m = rec = ""
}
```

```
$ awk -f filter.awk data.txt
2,22
22,22
222,22
2.222,22
22.222,22
222.222,22
2.222.222,22
```