# how to insert dots (.) in a string in bash scrip with sed or awk , 100000000 >> 100.000.000

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am writing a script that gives me a figure in millions 123456789 and I want to add the points to the numerical string like 123,456,789

```
:~$ a=100000000
:~$ b=100000000
:~$ c=100000000


:~$ tvusd=$(echo $(($a+$b+$c)))

:~$ echo $tvusd

:~$ 300000000
```

desired

```
:~$ echo $tvusd

:~$ 300.000.000
```

thanks

Comment: You could use GNU sed:  `sed -E ':a;s/([0-9])([0-9]{3}(\.[0-9]{3})*)$/\1.\2/;ta' <<<"$tvusd"`

Comment: Thanks @potong this is just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Just set LC_ALL to a locale that formats the number as you want then `printf` it with `'` in the format string, e.g.:

```
$ tvusd=300000000

$ LC_ALL=en_US printf "%'d\n" "$tvusd"
300,000,000

$ LC_ALL=en_ID printf "%'d\n" "$tvusd"
300.000.000
```

See [Unable to print period thousands separators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61910753/unable-to-print-period-thousands-separators/61911355#61911355) for more information on how to find a locale that formats it as you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`printf`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/printf.html) with a format string defining a number with thousand separators:

```
$ printf "%'d\n" "$tvusd"
300.000.000
```

Or [`numfmt`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/numfmt-invocation.html) of GNU coreutils:

```
$ numfmt --grouping "$tvusd"
300.000.000
```

It will use the thousands separator as defined by your current locale.

See also [Add thousands separator in a number](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/113795/add-thousands-separator-in-a-number) on Unix & Linux.

Answer (score 0):

[numfmt](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/numfmt-invocation.html)

> ‘`--grouping`’
> Group digits in output numbers according to the current locale’s grouping rules (e.g Thousands Separator character, commonly ‘.’ (dot) or ‘,’ comma). This option has no effect in ‘POSIX/C’ locale.

```
$ numfmt --grouping 100000000
100,000,000
```